# Cannot install older version of ImageMagick via Homebrew

Tags: installation, imagemagick, homebrew

I need to install ImageMagick 6.5.8 (or earlier might do), but even when I checkout an earlier commit, it installs the latest version (6.6.9-4).  I did this:

```
$ git checkout -b im-6.5.6 ff414bb
```

(then confirmed that the working tree shows the correct version of imagemagick.rb, with @url = a .tar of version 6.5.6-5)

```
$ brew install imagemagick
```

(and it says Checking out tag 6.6.9-4 and then proceeds to install that version)

Any help would be appreciated.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you managed to find a solution, if not. 
Heres one that worked for me on another related issue.

```
brew install https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/raw/master/versions/imagemagick-ruby186.rb
```

This will install ImageMagic 6.5.9-8