# Installing older version of imagemagick with homebrew

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew

I need to install an older version of imagemagick (6.5.9-3), I can see it in the list of available versions

```
> brew versions
6.6.1-5  git checkout 1c9f04e Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.5.9-8  git checkout 685dbff Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.5.9-3  git checkout 258720c Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.5.6-5  git checkout 7c90d02 Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
6.5.5-10 git checkout b01c13d Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
```

but when I checkout that version with

```
> git checkout 258720c Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
```

and then run

```
> brew install imagemagick
```

I get an error saying that

```
Error: imagemagick is a head-only formula
Install with `brew install --HEAD imagemagick
```

Why is brew listing those versions if it can't install them?
So the question remains, how to install an older version of imagemagick with brew?

(This solution is not working any longer: [Cannot install older version of ImageMagick via Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767968/cannot-install-older-version-of-imagemagick-via-homebrew#7473445))

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) formula in a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and install it with

```
brew install path/to/your/GistToYourPersonalImageMagickFormula
```

for example [here](https://gist.github.com/rochoa/10017167) or [here](https://gist.github.com/JagdeepSingh/4b03cbeab16cc0bc729bbc6d275402d3)

Comment: Sorry for the downvote but this method feels both like a security concern as well as very kludgy. I know it's what the Homebrew developers have suggested following the deprecation of the Boneyard but this should be handled another way.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for Ruby 1.8.6 compatibility, or any 6.5.9-x version will do, there is an ImageMagick 6.5.9.x formula provided as `imagemagick-ruby186` in the homebrew-versions tap. This will be easiest, and will be supported by future updates.

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install imagemagick-ruby186
```

Those 6.5.9.x versions of the original `imagemagick` formula are so old that they may have compatibility problems with the current `brew` ruby scripts. (They currently give "Formulae require at least a URL" errors; your error was probably a similar issue.) To get those to install, you'll probably have to roll back *all* of Homebrew to that point in time before doing the build, with a `git checkout` on the entire repo, not just the one file.

That other answer you linked will fail for the same reason - it's another mechanism of doing the same thing, just acquiring the old version of the `imagemagick.rb` formula via the web instead of through `git`, so it'll have the same compatibility problems.